# Can a Scanner from java.util.Scanner read copy pasted text?

Tags: java

I am trying to read an input with the Scanner (java.util.Scanner) class to encode text into base64. The issue I have is that I have to paste my text into the Input since its a bunch of long XML files. When I paste into the input i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at chriswb.Encoder.main(Encoder.java:21)
```

Gonna post my source code down below since its pretty short.

Basically whats happening is that when I insert ctrl+v it skips into the next Scanner.read which happens to be read.nextInt, thats why I'm getting a InputMismatchException.

What does ctrl+v do exactly in the command line?

Its pasting the text, but instead of reading it, it skips over my code into the next read line, triggering the exception.

Source code down below :

```
public class Encoder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 0;
    while (option != 1) {
            System.out.println("Write text : ");
            String content = read.nextLine();
            byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            content = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(content);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("0. Again");
            System.out.println("1. Close");
            option = read.nextInt();
            read.nextLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The scanner reads one line at a time, so if you paste anything with multiple lines then you will encounter this issue. You should repeat the while loop until there is no remaining content on the scanner `while(read.hasNext())` and only after that loop is complete should you try to get the integer input. Or another solution is to make sure that you don't scan for an integer until the scanner is empty `if(read.hasNext() == false){System.out.println("Enter your int"); option = read.nextInt();}`

Comment: You're trying to paste xml into a terminal? Don't! ;) Quite apart from line separator issues, you'll have worse ones in that your input will be full of shell-specific characters, namely redirection operators `<` and `>`. Base64 *de*coding of course shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @sorifiend some helpful info!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code you have shown in your post won't provide the exception you have said you're receiving but this is because you are now using the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method instead of the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method.

The [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method returns a token (or word) using the default white-space as a delimiter so, if you enter in a string and it contains more than one word separated with whitespaces then you will only be returned the first word. Also, that newline character that is added to the scanner buffer when you hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after supplying your text in console doesn't get consumed so it then naturally falls to the [Scanner#nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) method which of course generates the **InputMismatchException** for the simple reason that a newline character is not an integer digit. All **Scanner#next*XXX*** methods have this issue with the exception of the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method...it does consume the newline character.

If you only want the first word a User enters then by all means you can continue using the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method method but you will also need to take care of (consume) the newLine character supplied by the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key hit. You've done it where you utilized the [Scanner#nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm) method, now do it also for the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method, for example:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int option = 0;
while (option != 1) {
        System.out.println("Write text : ");
        String content = read.next();
        read.nextLine();
        byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        content = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(content);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("0. Again");
        System.out.println("1. Close");
        option = read.nextInt();
        read.nextLine();
}
```

Or, just keep using the Scanner#nextLine() method as your code currently demonstrates and if you want only the first word supplied by the User then utilize the String#split() method on the input string by that User, for example:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String with a few words separated by whitespaces: ");
String content = read.nextLine();
String[] words = content.split("\\s+"); // split on one (or more) whitespaces.
content = words[0]; // The first word
System.out.println("First Word: " + content);
```

Yes...you can paste text in the Console Window but nothing will happen until you hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Comment: Gonna give it a try now, thanks for the very insightful answer!